# How to make a solenoid armature travel at a faster rate of speed?

Tags: solenoid

My project requires a solenoid with a stroke of 15mm and the travel speed must be 15mm in 2ms. What can be done to get higher speed of travel in the armature?

Comment: If you have a look on the math behind the movement of the armature, you will see that not only the force exerted by the coil but also the mass of the armature plays a role: If you are able to reduce the mass of the armature, do so.

Answer (score 4):

You can drive the solenoid with a higher voltage.

As long as your duty-cycle is low enough that you don't have heating issues, it should work fine.

It's worth noting that 15 mm in 2 ms is pretty fast. That translates to 7.5 m/s, or 27 kph.

---

How big is your solenoid? Can you tell us more about the solenoids you are looking at?

Comment: Note: The speed you calculated is the *average* speed. If you assume a velocity of 0 at t=0 and a constant acceleration, the final velocity has to be twice that value.

Comment: To add to what @ox6d64 said, consider the energy requirement.  Let's say the total mass moved is 30 g.  With a final velocity of 15 m/s, that comes out to 3.4 J.  That plus any inefficiency has to be dumped onto the coil in a short time.  That's 82 V on a 1 mF capacitor, for example.

Answer (score 3):

What @Fakename and Olin said. Plus ...

Minimise mass to be accelerated.

Consider finding some other way of adding energy (may not be viable).

Reduce time constant:
Time constant = L/R
 If you can INCREASE R time constant goes down.
 But as t goes down so does current, so you need more V.
 So eg if a solenoid had a 100 ohm coil and was made to run from 12V the end current would be i=V/R = 12/100 = 120 mA.

BUT if you added a 900 ohm resistor in series and ran it from 120 V the end current would be the same BUT the time constant would be 10% of previous.

BUT 120V x 120 mA = ~14  Watt. Not terrible but not desirable.
SO instead running it from a constant current source achieves much of the same result.

Energy:
As Olin notes, there will be an energy calculation that show what you have to put in at absolute minimum. Noy=te that in his example mF is (correctly) miliFarad = 1,000 uF.